# How to get command output into function in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write simple script that compress specific directory periodically. Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> zipLogFile.log

log(){
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
        LEVEL=${1}
        MESSAGE=${2}
        echo "$LEVEL  $CURRENT_TIME  $MESSAGE"
else
        read IN
        LEVEL="INFO"
        echo "$LEVEL  $CURRENT_TIME  $IN"
fi
}

YESTERDAY=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d')
ROOT="/home/ubuntu/test"
YESTERDAY_DIR=$ROOT"/"$YESTERDAY

log "INFO" "checking directory $YESTERDAY_DIR"
if [ -d "$YESTERDAY_DIR" ]; then
        zip -r $ROOT"/"$YESTERDAY".zip" $ROOT"/"$YESTERDAY | log
        log "INFO" "Zip file $YESTERDAY_DIR.zip has been created"
else
        log "ERROR" "$YESTERDAY_DIR not exist."
fi
```

My problem is I want to get zip command's output to log function and print it from function. When I try to use pipe, it prints only first line of output and break zip command. Here is what I get in my logFile when I run script.

```
INFO  2017-05-21 15:09:22  checking directory /home/ubuntu/test/20170520
INFO  2017-05-21 15:09:22  adding: home/ubuntu/test/20170520/ (stored 0%)
INFO  2017-05-21 15:09:22  Zip file /home/ubuntu/test/20170520.zip has been created
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` will only read the first line, so your function then returns.  When `zip` next tries to write to that pipe it finds that the pipe has been closed (because the function exited) and itself exits.

Instead, you could read in a loop (assuming you want to use only the time at the start of the function):

```
else
    while read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s %s\n' "$LEVEL" "$CURRENT_TIME" "$line"
    done
fi
```

which you could actually just do with `sed` like

```
else
    sed -e "s/^/$LEVEL $CURRENT_TIME /"
fi
```

If you want the time for each line, you'll have to get the date on each iteration of the loop:

```
else
    while read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s %s\n' "$LEVEL" "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"
    done
fi
```